# Android development thread issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse, multithreading

I am making an android app in eclipse my problem is that every time I run it on my emulator it closes after 5 seconds and gives me a message “Unfortunately, ‘app name’ has stopped working”. I think this is due to the thread that brings up a picture I put in the drawable-hdpi folder because the thread is meant to bring up the picture for 5 seconds then start the program. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
package com.thenewboston.travis;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Splash extends Activity{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle t) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(t);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);
 new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
            sleep(5000);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                Intent openStartingPoint= new Intent("com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT");
                startActivity(openStartingPoint);
            }
        }
    }.start(); }}
```

The Android Manifest Code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.thenewboston.travis"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.Splash"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.thenewboston.travis.startingPoint"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

And this is my splash file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/yaron_dynamics">


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> should be default <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />. also new Intent(com.thenewboston.travis.startingPoint)

Comment: The first activity is working but it looks like the second one never starts which is what causes the program to end. How can I call on the startingPoint file after the Handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can not `startActivity` in a thread different from the UI thread

Comment: The first activity is working but it looks like the second one never starts which is what causes the program to end. How can I call on the startingPoint file after the Handler?

Answer (score 1):

You can't launch an `Activity` from a background thread. Instead of a thread, use a `Handler`:

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
       Intent i = new Intent("com.thenewboston.travis.STARTINGPOINT");
       startActivity(i);
   }
};

new Handler().postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Comment: Whatever you were doing to launch your Activity before your came here :) there, edited

Comment: So I removed the previous thread and added the code above as well as changing the second activity in the manifest to default but it still closes after 5 second and gives me that message.

Comment: Then the problem is elsewhere. Maybe the second `Activity` you launch. Maybe the `Intent` is wrong. I see, for example, that you call your `Activity` both `STARTINGPOINT` (upper-case) and `startingPoint`

Comment: The first activity is working but it looks like the second one never starts which is what causes the program to end. How can I call on the startingPoint file after the Handler?